# for-loop, callback, timeout together, timeout seems not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback, settimeout

I have a use case, I need to use for-loop, webservice callback, timeout together, then I found timeout seemed not working, here is the code:

```
function handler5Min(i){
            if (i < sites.length){
                var site5MinPath = '/v3/sites/' + sites[i].siteid + '/data?fields=Wh_sum&tz=US/Pacific&gran=daily';
                var end = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss');
                var start = moment().subtract(2, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss');
                site5MinPath = site5MinPath + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end;

                var options = locusUtil.setOptions(site5MinPath, globalToken.token.access_token);
                request(options, function(err, result, body){
                    if (err){
                        log.error(err + ' path: ' + site5MinPath);
                    }
                    if (body){
                        var data = JSON.parse(body).data;
                        log.info('5 min data: ' + JSON.stringify(body, null, 4));
                        setTimeout(handler5Min(i+1), 5000);
                    }
                })
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        handler5Min(0);
```

request is sending out a webservice request, i need to wait until got response then I move to next site[] item to make next call, but also, the API provider limit the request as 2 per second, so i have a setTimeout there, but seems the timeout did not happen.

Comment: You must pass a function to `setTimeout`. Your *call*  doesn't produce one. Use a function expression.

Comment: that's true, a silly mistake by me, i thought directly calling the function is the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
setTimeout(handler5Min(i+1), 5000);
```

do

```
setTimeout(handler5Min, 5000, i + 1);
```